# Read Array Value Using Dataweave in Mule

Tags: json, mule, mule-component, dataweave, mule-esb

I am trying to use dataweave in Mule to read specific data values from an incoming payload. My sample payload looks like below:

```
 {
    "source": [
        {
            "uri": "entities/1R6xV",
            "createdBy": "API_USER",
            "createdTime": 1562504739146,
            "attributes": {
                "label": "000000000002659654",
                "value": {
                    "Name": [
                        {
                        }
                    ],
                    "Id": [
                        {
                        }
                    ],
                    "Number": [
                        {
                            "type": "config/Types/Number/attributes/Number",
                            "ov": true,
                            "value": "000000000002659654",
                            "uri": "entities/1R6xV/attributes/Num/1ZtyT/Number/60pvN6"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I need to read the "label", I can achieve that by

```
label: payload.source.attributes.label
```

Similarly, how can I read the "value" under attributes > Number. It doesn't work by:

```
Value: payload.source.attributes.Number.value
```

I am new to Dataweave. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the dot selector (.) works on object and on array of objects. When it is applied to an array it will apply the dot selector to all the elements of the array that are of type object and return that result.

Lets go part by part

```
payload.source
```

**Returns**

```
[
  {
    "uri": "entities/1R6xV",
    "createdBy": "API_USER",
    "createdTime": 1562504739146,
    "attributes": {
      "label": "000000000002659654",
      "value": {
        "Name": [
          {

          }
        ],
        "Id": [
          {

          }
        ],
        "Number": [
          {
            "type": "config/Types/Number/attributes/Number",
            "ov": true,
            "value": "000000000002659654",
            "uri": "entities/1R6xV/attributes/Num/1ZtyT/Number/60pvN6"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

So far so good as payload is an Object it returns the value of source that is an array

```
payload.source.attributes
```

**Returns**

```
[
  {
    "label": "000000000002659654",
    "value": {
      "Name": [
        {

        }
      ],
      "Id": [
        {

        }
      ],
      "Number": [
        {
          "type": "config/Types/Number/attributes/Number",
          "ov": true,
          "value": "000000000002659654",
          "uri": "entities/1R6xV/attributes/Num/1ZtyT/Number/60pvN6"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Works ok because the result of *payload.source* was ended an Array of object so it will do that selection over those objects.

Now when you execute

```
payload.source.attributes.value.Number
```

It returns

```
[
  [
    {
      "type": "config/Types/Number/attributes/Number",
      "ov": true,
      "value": "000000000002659654",
      "uri": "entities/1R6xV/attributes/Num/1ZtyT/Number/60pvN6"
    }
  ]
]
```

That is an array of arrays and here is where it is broken.

**My Solution**

You have two alternatives here

- Use **flatten** function

  flatten(payload.source.attributes.value.Number).value
- Use **descendant** selector

  payload.source.attributes.value.Number..value

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It really helps! Let me give this a try and will reach out if there are any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since Number is an array, you need to specify the index you want. In this case, the zeroth element:

`Value: payload.source[0].attributes.value.Number[0].value`

If you have multiple numbers, it would look something like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
values: payload.source[0].attributes.value.Number map {
    value: $.value
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I will try this out.